# For loop creating dataframes

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

I have this vector

```
panelcustomers <- c(40482, 37244, 17734, 39786, 42613, 45703, 9534, 41772, 42358, 23870, 21815, 29070, 14248, 29484, 12720, 11951, 28290, 9245, 617, 17850, 44827, 29726, 30967, 36267, 37724, 37868, 33041, 37412, 42226, 41701, 26931, 15634, 29180, 35254, 33668, 18337, 31376, 16439, 26222, 7122, 35112, 38161, 23269, 35577, 24493, 1379, 36592, 40487, 8144, 39453, 6361, 34777, 17886, 33273, 11647, 34762, 25881, 5094, 55336, 13427, 28155, 46457, 54933, 42932, 52650, 40607, 15742, 15403, 27240, 28521, 23076, 46817, 39350, 44987, 34671, 53260, 39353, 52295, 56728)
```

and would like to use a for loop to iterate through the vector, executing the following code:

```
pc17734_it <- subset(Paneldataexport,Paneldataexport$V1 == 17734 & Paneldataexport$V2 == "inside_temperature" & Paneldataexport$V3 <= turningpoint['17734',])
pc17734_st <- subset(Paneldataexport,Paneldataexport$V1 == 17734 & Paneldataexport$V2 == "set_point_temperature" & Paneldataexport$V3 <= turningpoint['17734',])
pi17734_it <- subset(Paneldataexport,Paneldataexport$V1 == 17734 & Paneldataexport$V2 == "inside_temperature" & Paneldataexport$V3 > turningpoint['17734',])
pi17734_st <- subset(Paneldataexport,Paneldataexport$V1 == 17734 & Paneldataexport$V2 == "set_point_temperature" & Paneldataexport$V3 > turningpoint['17734',])
interpol_pc17734_it <- approx(pc17734_it$V3, pc17734_it$V4, method = "linear", n=8352, rule = 2)
interpol_pc17734_st <- approx(pc17734_st$V3, pc17734_st$V4, xout =      interpol_pc17734_it$x, method = "constant", rule = 1:2)
interpol_pi17734_it <- approx(pi17734_it$V3, pi17734_it$V4, method = "linear", n=432, rule = 2)
interpol_pi17734_st <- approx(pi17734_st$V3, pi17734_st$V4, xout = interpol_pi17734_it$x, method = "constant", rule = 1:2)
interpol_pc17734_it$st <- interpol_pc17734_st$y
names(interpol_pc17734_it)[names(interpol_pc17734_it) == 'y'] <- 'it'
pc17734 <- interpol_pc17734_it
interpol_pi17734_it$st <- interpol_pi17734_st$y
names(interpol_pi17734_it)[names(interpol_pi17734_it) == 'y'] <- 'it'
pi17734 <- interpol_pi17734_it
remove(pc17734_it, pc17734_st, pi17734_it, pi17734_st, interpol_pc17734_it,     interpol_pc17734_st, interpol_pi17734_it, interpol_pi17734_st)
```

For each iteration, the number (in this example 17734) should be replaced with the next number in the vector - so that in the end, the resulting dataframe has the name according to the number (in this example pi17734 from the second last row). Any idea how to loop through this code? Thank you!

Comment: You don't need all the intermediaries in the end, do you? Only the dataset (in this case `pi7734`)?

Comment: Yes, only pi17734 (second last row) as well as pc17734 (5th last row)

Comment: Do the `n`-values stay the same for the whole loop? Or are they accessible in the subsets?

Comment: for pi, the n value always needs to be 432, for pc the n value always needs to be 8352 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is untested (as you did not provide any example data) and it is NOT a good way to work, as the function I wrote you assigns objects to the global environment (which you usually shouldn't do). But this is the only way I found for using your desired naming scheme.

```
myfun <- function(x) {
    a <- subset(Paneldataexport,Paneldataexport$V1 == x & 
                Paneldataexport$V2 == "inside_temperature" & 
                Paneldataexport$V3 <= turningpoint[paste0(x),])
    b <- subset(Paneldataexport,Paneldataexport$V1 == x &
                Paneldataexport$V2 == "set_point_temperature" &
                Paneldataexport$V3 <= turningpoint[paste0(x),])
    c <- subset(Paneldataexport,Paneldataexport$V1 == x &
                Paneldataexport$V2 == "inside_temperature" &
                Paneldataexport$V3 > turningpoint[paste0(x),])
    d <- subset(Paneldataexport,Paneldataexport$V1 == x &
                Paneldataexport$V2 == "set_point_temperature" &
                Paneldataexport$V3 > turningpoint[paste0(x),])
    a1 <- approx(a$V3, a$V4, method = "linear", n=8352, rule = 2)
    b1 <- approx(b$V3, b$V4, xout = a1$x, method = "constant", rule = 1:2)
    c1 <- approx(c$V3, c$V4, method = "linear", n=432, rule = 2)
    d1 <- approx(d$V3, d$V4, xout = c1$x, method = "constant", rule = 1:2)

    a1$st <- b1$y
    names(a1)[names(a1) == 'y'] <- 'it'
    assign(paste0("pc", x), a1, envir = globalenv())
    c1$st <- d1$y
    names(c1)[names(c1) == 'y'] <- 'it'
    assign(paste0("pi", x), c1, envir = globalenv())
}
```

Loop this function over your vector, e.g. with `sapply(panelcustomers, myfun)` and at the end you should have all your desired dataframes.

A better way to do this would be to save all the dataframes in one list, so you would not need the use of `assign`.

Edit: Note that, depending on the size of your data, this might take pretty long to compute!

2nd edit: Removed some brackets.

3rd edit: This might be a solution without global.env-assignment. You can feed your vector directly into the function and it should return a list containing `a1` and `c1`, which themselves will be lists of the datasets.

```
myfun2 <- function(x) {
    a <- lapply(x, function(z) subset(Paneldataexport,Paneldataexport$V1 == z & 
                Paneldataexport$V2 == "inside_temperature" & 
                Paneldataexport$V3 <= turningpoint[paste0(z),]))
    b <- lapply(x, function(z) subset(Paneldataexport,Paneldataexport$V1 == z &
                Paneldataexport$V2 == "set_point_temperature" &
                Paneldataexport$V3 <= turningpoint[paste0(z),]))
    c <- lapply(x, function(z) subset(Paneldataexport,Paneldataexport$V1 == z &
                Paneldataexport$V2 == "inside_temperature" &
                Paneldataexport$V3 > turningpoint[paste0(z),]))
    d <- lapply(x, function(x) subset(Paneldataexport,Paneldataexport$V1 == z &
                Paneldataexport$V2 == "set_point_temperature" &
                Paneldataexport$V3 > turningpoint[paste0(z),]))
    a1 <- lapply(a, function(z) approx(z$V3, z$V4, method = "linear", n=8352, rule = 2)
    b1 <- lapply(b, function(z) approx(z$V3, z$V4, xout = a1$x, method = "constant", rule = 1:2)
    c1 <- lapply(c, function(z) approx(z$V3, z$V4, method = "linear", n=432, rule = 2)
    d1 <- lapply(d, function(z) approx(z$V3, z$V4, xout = c1$x, method = "constant", rule = 1:2)

    a1$st <- b1$y
    names(a1)[names(a1) == 'y'] <- 'it'
    c1$st <- d1$y
    names(c1)[names(c1) == 'y'] <- 'it'
    datalist <- list(a1, c1)
    return(datalist)
}
```

Use it like this: `mydata <- myfun2(panelcustomers)`. Again, this is all untested.

Comment: thank you! Second brackets at the end of assignment b and c needed to be removed, after that it worked perfectly!